# JavaFX : Draggable node (Label ) horizontally only not vertically

Tags: javafx

Scenario : I want to drag (Drag gable Node) i.e  labels(series of labels) in horizontal direction inside JFXPanel and it should be fixed vertically ....

I am referring [Link](https://gist.github.com/miho/3821180) .....but i am not able to restrict user to drag vertically so someone help me....the labels should be drag horizontal only not vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example. I commented out the Y translating, so that you can drag the label only horizontally.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragNodesHorizontally extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        // create label
        Label label = new Label( "Drag me");
        label.relocate(100,100);

        // make label draggable
        MouseGestures mg = new MouseGestures();
        mg.makeDraggable( label);

        root.getChildren().addAll( label);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static class MouseGestures {

        class DragContext {
            double x;
            double y;
        }

        DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        public void makeDraggable( Node node) {
            node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged( onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {

                Node node = ((Node) (event.getSource()));

                dragContext.x = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = event -> {

                Node node = ((Node) (event.getSource()));

                node.setTranslateX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
//                  node.setTranslateY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY()); // uncomment this if you want x/y dragging

        };
    }
}
```

In the link you posted, you could as well set offsetY to 0.